# Difference between fs.writeFile and fs.writeStream

Tags: node.js

I'm a little confused between the 2 methods, hope somebody could enlighten 
me on the difference between `fs.open->fs.write`, `fs.writeFile`, `fs.writeStream`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`fs.open` and `fs.write` are for low-level access, similar to what you get when you code in C. `fs.open` opens a file and `fs.write` writes to it.

A `fs.WriteStream` is a stream that opens the file in the background and queues writes until the file is ready. Also, as it implements the stream API, you can use it in a more generic way, just like a network stream or so. You'll e.g. want this when a user uploads a file to your server - take the incoming HTTP POST stream, `pipe()` it to the `WriteStream`. Very easy.

`fs.writeFile` is a high-level method for writing a bunch of data you have in RAM to a file. It doesn't support streaming or so, so it's a bad idea for large files or performance-critical stuff. You'll want this if you write out small JSON files or so in your code.

Comment: So `WriteStream` would be faster than even `write`?

Comment: @3zzy Streamed data transfers are inherently slower, as they're handled in chunks, however, they're friendly on RAM (because you don't require the entire file in memory).

Comment: is it still the case that `fs.write` is preferred over `fs.writeFile` for everything but rewriting small json files?

Comment: WriteStream is way faster than fs.write for small chunks. On my linux box with an SSD, writing a Buffer(4), file.write is 5x faster than fs.writeSync. They are the same performance for a Buffer(100*1000).