# Node.js WriteStream synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a purely synchronous, single threaded command line program in node.js, which needs to write a single binary file, for which I'm using `WriteStream`. My usage pattern is along the lines of:

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(file)
stream.write(buf1)
stream.write(buf2)
```

This seems to work, but the documentation says it's asynchronous and I want to make sure I'm not writing code that works 99% of the time. I don't care exactly when the data gets written as long as it's written in the specified order and no later than when the program exits, and the quantity of data is small so speed and memory consumption are not issues.

I've seen mention of `stream.end()` but it seems to work without it and I've also seen suggestions that calling it may actually be a bad idea if you're not using callbacks because it might end up getting called before all the data is written.

Is my approach correct (given that I want purely synchronous) or is there anything I need to watch out for?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this would fit into your use case (and recognize that it may not be quite what you're looking for) but have you considered just using `fs.write` as a synchronous option? http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback

Comment: @imjared Good question! the synchronous version of that would seem to do the job. What's the difference between the two? or put another way, given the existence of that, what's the reason for the existence of WriteStream? Is WriteStream intended primarily for writing text?

Comment: to be perfectly honest I don't have the best understanding of streams but whenever I've needed a synchronous approach to writing something. Here's a much better explanation than I could give: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8770026/628699

Comment: Node is very centered around async IO. Why are you focusing so heavily on making all of your logic synchronous?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Because I'm writing a straightforward command line program that by its nature has nothing to do with async IO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, the only problem can be if you create two or more concurrent streams for the same path: the order of writes from different streams will be undefined. By the way, there is a synchronous fs write stream implementation in node: `fs.SyncWriteStream`. It's kind of private and requires `fd` as an argument, but if you really want it...

Comment: You don't have to use `fs.SyncWriteStream`. Just do a `fd = openSync` and then do a `readSync` using that `fd`.

Comment: What's the API? How can I invoke this function. An example would be pretty helpful!

Comment: Warning, fs.syncWriteStream has now been deprecated: https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0061_fs_syncwritestream

Comment: `fs.syncWriteStream` is deprecated and no longer available in new Node.js releases. Use `fs.OpenSync` with `fs.WriteSync`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a timing-critical API, where a new file has to have been written and its stream completely handled before the next action can be performed.  The solution, in my case (and, quite possibly, that of the OP's question) was to use:

```
writer.on('finish', () => {
 console.error('All writes are now complete.');
});
```

as per the [`fs Event: 'finish'` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish)

Comment: `finish` event called when `end` event occurred. But in this case, dont know when exactly writing will complete, so `finish` will not work this scenario.

Comment: No, according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) `finish` is only called when `end` has occurred and all data has been flushed to disk.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const writeToLocalDisk = (stream, path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const istream = stream;
    const ostream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    istream.pipe(ostream);
    istream.on("end", () => {
      console.log(`Fetched ${path} from elsewhere`);
      resolve();
    });
    istream.on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

// Then use an async function to perform sequential-like operation

async function sequential (stream) {
  const path = "";
  await writeToLocalDisk(stream, path);
  console.log('other operation here');
}
```