# Express js Creating folder and removing folder causes error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Create Folder Code in index.js**

```
let companydir = './views/campaigns/' + companyname;
    if(!fs.existsSync(companydir, { recursive: true })) {
        fs.mkdirSync(companydir, { recursive: true });
    }
    var dir = companydir + '/' + nameToGenerate;
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir, { recursive: true })) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
        var build = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/index.jade', {
            flags: 'a'
        });
```

**remove folder code in index.js**

```
fs.rmSync('./views/campaigns/' + companyname + '/' + deletetarget, { recursive: true, force: true });
```

If I run NPM start any folders previously created in the campaigns folder can be removed. But any folders created and then deleted in the same instance always errors with the following error:

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '<pathurl that is now emptied>'
    at Object.rmdirSync (node:fs:1227:10)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:260:21)
    at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
    at Object.rmSync (node:fs:1276:10)
    at Query.<anonymous> (<pathurl>routes\index.js:192:10)
    at Query.<anonymous> (<pathurl>\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (<pathurl>\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (<pathurl>\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (<pathurl>\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (<pathurl>\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8) {
  errno: -4051,
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
  path: '<pathurl>'
}
```

It does delete the index.jade file that I put inside the folder. It seems to be erroring when trying to remove the folder its self even tho the folder is empty.
It works perfectly fine if I terminate the job and then start it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question I worked it out, and decided to share my solution encase anyone else has a similar issue.

```
var build = fs.createWriteStream(dir + '/index.jade', {
    flags: 'a'
});
```

The "`createWriteStream`" was the problem. It needed to be swapped to a SYNC function

```
let data = "test";
fs.writeFileSync(dir + '/test.txt', data);
```

This was my fix and it works perfectly for what I need.

**Futher reading:**

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefilesync-method/

[Node.js WriteStream synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468830/node-js-writestream-synchronous#comment101899541_24469319)